# Linear Programming - Proof of symmetry in primal-dual relationship

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm reading through an optimization textbook that omits the proof for the symmetry of the primal and dual linear programs. That is, I would like to know why the dual of

$~~~~~~~~~~\min c^Tx$ subject to $Ax \geq b$, $x \geq 0$

is

$~~~~~~~~~~\max b^T \lambda$ subject to $A^T \lambda \leq c$, $\lambda \geq 0$.

Here we are assuming that $A$ is m x n, $c$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $b$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

So far, I have that the primal problem is equivalent to:

$~~~~~~~~~~~\max (-c)^Tx$ subject to $ (-A)x \leq -b$,

but I'm not sure where to go from here.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Note that the program $\max b^T \lambda $ subject to $A^T \lambda \le c $, $\lambda \ge 0$ can be written as $\min (-b)^T \lambda $ subject to $(-A^T) \lambda \ge c $, $\lambda \ge 0$. Now apply the "dual rule" to this program and you end up with the primal.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the dual rule is?

Comment: It was a little tongue in cheek, but if the primal is parametrised by $(c,A,b)$ then the dual is $(-b, A^T, -c)$. Applying the formal map one more time results in $(c,A,b)$. (Note, I made a small mistake in my previous comment, I should have had a $-c$ there too.)